# What kind of international code is used for identifying countries like

Tags: api, search, internationalization

I need the name of the code in with:

- ROM: Roma, Italy
- BCN: Barcelona, Spain
- MAD: Madrid, Spain
- BUE: Buenos Aires, Argentina
- PCM: Playa del Carmen, Mexico
- PAR: Paris, France
- LON: London, UK
- etc...

I am developing an app that searches flights between countries and I need a full list of this kind of codes to interatct with another third party API.

I tried to google it but the only things that apears are flight sites instead of a wikipedia page or something.

Can you give me any pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [IATA (3 letter) Airport Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code).

This list may help you:

http://www.photius.com/wfb2001/airport_codes_alpha.html.

You could also use the official [IATA search engine](http://www.iata.org/ps/publications/Pages/code-search.aspx) (*Location code* category).

If you want an officially sanctionned list, you apparently [need to pay a hefty price](http://www.iata.org/ps/publications/Pages/acd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'World Airport Codes' search query and Google's your uncle. Below are some links from my search:

[World Airport Codes](http://www.world-airport-codes.com/)
[Airport Codes](http://www.airportcodes.org/)
[Localized World Airport Codes](http://www.halfgaar.net/localized-world-airport-codes)
[Openflights](http://openflights.org/data.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [IATA airport codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code):

> The assignment of these codes is governed by IATA Resolution 763, and
>   it is administered by IATA headquarters in Montreal. The codes are
>   published biannually in the IATA Airline Coding Directory.

Unfortunately, that authoritative list is quite expensive. But I am certain you can find many unofficial lists by searching the web.